# Insert record, retrieve ID then insert into second table PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert into 2 tables with PDO MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059172/insert-into-2-tables-with-pdo-mysql)

Im trying to insert data into 2 tables, my problem is in 1 table i have an ID that is automatically incremented, I then want to insert into another table. At the minute as I don't know how to solve this im passing a hidden field input using rand(); and inserting that field into both queries, only sometimes the web pages may get cached and some records are being overwritten, I hope this makes sense?

```
  $sql = "

  INSERT INTO `directory` (`First_Name`,`Surname`,`Nicknames` ) VALUES (:firstname, :surname, :nicknames);

  INSERT INTO `user_sightings` (`UID`, `postcode`) VALUES (:uid, :lastseenpostcode);

  ";
```

Comment: Can you explain what fields are in the two tables and how those tables relate to each other.  I am not seeing a common field in your queries.

Comment: Begin transaction, insert into first table, get ID of latest insert, insert into second table, commit transaction.

Answer (score 3):

Use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in your second query.

```
  $sql = "

  INSERT INTO `directory` (`First_Name`,`Surname`,`Nicknames` ) VALUES (:firstname, :surname, :nicknames);

  INSERT INTO `user_sightings` (`UID`, `postcode`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), :lastseenpostcode);

  ";
```

Comment: while this is nice. I can yield some SQL injection issues, since you are sending more than once query at the time. I would say user _stores procedures_ or do it using PHP methods, (and if you would like use transactions)