# Insert values into multiple tables with single query

Tags: mysql, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Insert into multiple tables? (Database normalization?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization)

I am looking to insert values into two separate tables with a single query using MySQL. Is this possible?

I have tried Google but it is not coming up with anything like what I am looking for. I have a form a user fills out and it needs to put different field values in different tables, I figured it would be more efficient using one query instead of two.

Comment: I'm not sure but i dont think so , take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I don't see how using one query would *really* be more efficient IMHO you have at least following options:

1. Use a STORED PROCEDURE
2. Use an INSERT TRIGGER (eg on a stagging table)
3. Assuming that you use PHP for server side scripting technically you can use [`multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) but that posses a great security risk and doesn't make inserts atomic.

Comment: +1. I would say a SP is the OP's best choice. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) on multi-query.