# mysql query one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+---------+    +-----------+   +---------+
| USER    |    | USER_LANG |   | LANG    |
| id_user |    | id_user   |   | id_lang |
| name    |    | id_lang   |   | name    |
|         |    | years     |   |         |
+---------+    +-----------+   +---------+
```

I want to write query for saving data from user and user_lang in database at same time...is there some insert join or what?

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5178697

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. You can only select or delete from multiple tables at once.

Answer (score 0):

If table structure would have been same; it would have been possible. But in your case you will have to use multiple queries. If you want to ensure integrity between table data then use Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   INSERT INTO LANG (id_lang,name) 
   VALUES    (SELECT ul.id_lang ,u.name 
              FROM `USER` u
              INNER JOIN `USER_LANG` ul 
              ON  u.id_user = ul.id_user 
              )
```