# "BEGIN..COMMIT;" fails in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to learn how to use `BEGIN ... COMMIT` in SQLite. I'm trying this code:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO fields VALUES ('field1')
COMMIT;
```

but it fails with

```
Error: near "INSERT": syntax error
```

When using just the insert statement, it succeeds, though:

```
INSERT INTO fields VALUES ('field1');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have it in a transaction you must end each statement with ;

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO fields VALUES ('field1');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Ok, then its just because you forgot the ; in the transaction

Comment: I took the example from http://stackoverflow.com/a/5178713/492336, but the example was for MySQL.