# How to Insert a query into two diff table vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm having trouble inserting an item from two different tables using a vb.net and MySql

This is Item table and Stocks Table in a single query:

```
Dim rsitem As New ADODB.Recordset

    rsitem.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
    rsitem.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic
    rsitem.Open("Insert Into items,stocks itemno = '" & txtItemNo.Text & "', Description = '" & txtDescription.Text & "', Price = '" & txtPrice.Text & "', Brand = '" & txtBrand.Text & "', stocks_on_hand = '" & txtStocks.text &"'",cn)
```

My problem is when I type in inputbox the txtStocks.text doesn't show what I input from my vb.net  into  mysql db. I think I have a wrong query. Can someone help me. ?

Comment: You are right. Your query is so wrong. Please look up the syntax in the docs.

Comment: You'll also want to be **extremely** careful when inserting data like that and use the proper quoting mechanism available. Prepared statements with placeholders make this much easier to get right.

Comment: Do you really have two tables with identical columns?  That sounds like a broken data model.  Either way, generally inserting into two tables is achieved by executing two `INSERT` statements.  Also, be aware that you have a wide open SQL injection vulnerability.  Your query may not work, but whatever query the user enters for you can work just fine.

Comment: i know my query is wrong but when just inserting a item from table item is working , but now that i have a diff two table my code doesn't work, and can you give some link? or some related problem like that? if that is ok?

Comment: @divid yes i have the itemNo. and i think i miss some thing here don't know ?
Insert Into items,stocks itemno = '" & txtItemNo.Text & "

Comment: Please don't use values taken directly from user entered controls (`TextBox`).  Validate and normalize the values and then use a parameterized statement or stored procedure.  Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization may be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly you need to make sure that the textboxes are not empty
2. Then concerning your `rsitem.Open`, I saw you Open it twice.
3. Thirdly, your query is wrong! whats the name of your Table you wish to insert into? I guess it's *items*?

You can try the following;

```
If not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtItemNo.Text) Orelse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDescription.Text) Orelse _
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPrice.Text) Orelse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBrand.Text) Orelse _
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStocks.Text) Then

    rsitem.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
    rsitem.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic
    rsitem.Open(String.format( _
                "Insert Into items (itemno, Description, Price, Brand, stocks_on_hand) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}') ", _
    txtItemNo.Text, txtDescription.Text, txtPrice.Text, txtBrand.Text, txtStocks.text), connection) 

End If
```

Comment: Hello @Nadeem_MK im new in vb.net and also in mysql i also have a code   to check if  the textboxes is empty. but can i suggest can i use this code? 
rsitem.Open("Insert Into items , stocks itemno = '" & txtItemNo.Text & "', Description = '" & txtDescription.Text & "', Price = '" & txtPrice.Text & "', Brand = '" & txtBrand.Text & "', STOCKS_ON_HAND = '" & txtStock.Text & "", cn)

i know the query is wrong but can i use that and make it work?

Comment: Ohh! How can you check for the textboxes in mySQL? No your query is wrong.

Comment: thats why I mentionned, you should check your textboxes values before. You can do the following `rsitem.Open("Insert Into items ( itemno,Description,Price,Brand,STOCKS_ON_HAND) values ('" & txtItemNo.Text & "', '" & txtDescription.Text & "', '" & txtPrice.Text & "', '" & txtBrand.Text & "', '" & txtStock.Text & "')", cn)`