# SQL Multiple Tables Insertion

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

So I'm new to the use of multiple tables. Prior to today, 1 table suited my needs (and I could probably get away with using 1 here as well).

I'm creating a plugin for a game I play but I'm using a MySQL database to store all the information. I have 3 tables, Players, Warners and Warns. Warns has 2 foreign keys in it (one referencing to Players and the other to Warners).

At the moment I need to do 3 queries. Add the information to Players & Warners, and then to Warns. Is there a way I can cut down the amount of queries and what would happen if I were to just omit the first 2 queries?

Query Examples:

```
INSERT INTO slimewarnsplayers VALUES ('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000', 'Spedwards');

INSERT INTO slimewarnswarners VALUES ('f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479', '_Sped');

INSERT INTO slimewarnswarns VALUES ('', '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000', 'f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479', 'spamming', 'medium');
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SlimeWarnsPlayers (
    uuid VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (uuid)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SlimeWarnsWarners (
    uuid VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (uuid)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SlimeWarnsWarns (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    pUUID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    wUUID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    warning VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    level VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (pUUID) REFERENCES SlimeWarnsPlayers(uuid),
    FOREIGN KEY (wUUID) REFERENCES SlimeWarnsWarners(uuid)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way I can cut down the amount of queries?

NO, I don't see that. From your posted `INSERT` statements (as depicted below) it's clear that those are 3 different tables and you are inserting different data to them. so, you will have to perform the `INSERT` operation separately for them.

```
INSERT INTO slimewarnsplayers 

INSERT INTO slimewarnswarners 

INSERT INTO slimewarnswarns
```

Another option would be (May not be considered good), creating a procedure which will accept the data and table name and create a prepared statement/dynamic query to achieve what you are saying. something like (A sample pseudo code)

```
create procedure sp_insert(tablename varchar(10), data1 varchar(10), 
                                                  data2 varchar(10))
as
begin
--dynamic query here
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (data1, data2);
end
```

To explain further, you can then call this procedure from your application end passing the required data. Do note that, if you have a Foreign Key relationship with other table then you will have to catch the `last inserted key` from your master table and then pass the same to procedure.

Comment: That are two entities, one relation (which references the other two inserts), the correct foreign keys, so it needs three inserts.

Comment: @lx42.de, absolutely correct. Though using dynamic query is also possible (you will have to catch the last inserted key value from master table) but I wouldn't go for it; but worth mentioning once.

Comment: I didnt catch (the benefit) of your idea, because you can get the latest insert id and not the last two ones (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) you have to insert, mem=LAST_INSERT_ID(), insert, insert(mem, LAST_INSERT_ID(), ...) resulting in four queries.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't insert into multiple tables in one MySQL command. You can however use transactions.

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO slimewarnsplayers VALUES(.....);
 last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
INSERT INTO SlimeWarnsWarners VALUES(last_id, ....);
INSERT INTO SlimeWarnsWarns VALUES(last_id, ....);
COMMIT;
```

I would also take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

and this post [MySQL Insert into multiple tables? (Database normalization?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization)