# Update in two tables at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to update two tables at the same time? I have a table `food` and table `food_r`

This is the code with which I insert into food

```
$rest_id = null;
if ( !empty($_GET['rest_id'])) 
{
    $rest_id = $_REQUEST['rest_id'];
}
if ( null==$rest_id ) 
{
    echo "null==$rest_id";
}
if(isSet($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    // keep track post values
    $food_name = $_POST['food_name'];
    $food_description = $_POST['food_description'];
    $food_menu = $rest_id;
    $usertype = $_SESSION['usertype'];

     // update data
     $pdo = Database::connect();
     $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO food ( food_name, food_description, food_menu, usertype ) 
              VALUES (:food_name, :food_description, :food_menu, :usertype)");

                    $sql->execute(array(
                    ':food_name'    => $food_name,
                    ':food_description' => $food_description,
                    ':food_menu'    => $food_id,
                    ':usertype'     => $_SESSION['usertype']                        
                    ));
                    Database::disconnect();
                    echo "Product added!";
            }
```

Now If I want to be visible the inserted product I must insert in table `food_r` value of `food_menu` and the value of `usertype`. 
How can I do this?

**Update: It's working that way. Thank's to @JonathonWisnoski for pointing me to transactions.**.

```
  $pdo->beginTransaction();
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO food ( food_name, food_description, food_menu, usertype ) 
                VALUES (:food_name, :food_description, :food_menu, :usertype)");

        $sql->execute(array(
        ':food_name'    => $food_name,
        ':food_description' => $food_description,
        ':food_menu'    => $rest_id,
        ':usertype'     => $_SESSION['usertype']                        
        ));
        $lastInsertID = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO food_r (food_id, usertype) 
                    VALUES (:rest_id, :usertype)");
        $sql->execute(array(
        ':rest_id'      => $lastInsertID,
        ':usertype' => $rest_id
        ));
        $pdo->commit();
```

Comment: This is something you would do with transactions. The general idea behind transactions is to ready a number of insersions/etc. And to commit them all at once.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization

Comment: Do you want to insert into or to update the two tables?

Comment: You can UPDATE two tables at the same time. You cannot INSERT into two tables at the same time. I'm unclear as to what it is you're actually trying to do.

Comment: When I hit button `submit` on the form I insert new row(record) in table `food`. The product is still not visible because I must also insert the values from `food_menu` and `usertype` into the table `food_r`.

Comment: I have updated my question with how I've made it and it's working.

Comment: @JasonPaddle do NOT update question by adding answer. If you solved your problem post normal **answer** and when SO allows, approve it

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, thank's for your comment. I will post this working sniped like answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: It's working that way. Thank's to @JonathonWisnoski for pointing me to transactions.**.

I've also put `try{}catch{}` block for any errors.

```
 try 
 {
   $pdo->beginTransaction();
     $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO food ( food_name, food_description, food_menu, usertype ) 
                VALUES (:food_name, :food_description, :food_menu, :usertype)");

        $sql->execute(array(
        ':food_name'    => $food_name,
        ':food_description' => $food_description,
        ':food_menu'    => $rest_id,
        ':usertype'     => $_SESSION['usertype']                        
        ));
        $lastInsertID = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO food_r (food_id, usertype) 
                    VALUES (:rest_id, :usertype)");
        $sql->execute(array(
        ':rest_id'      => $lastInsertID,
        ':usertype' => $rest_id
        ));
        $pdo->commit();
   }                
   // any errors from the above database queries will be catched
   catch (PDOException $e)
   {
        // roll back transaction
        $pdo->rollback();
        // log any errors to file
        ExceptionErrorHandler($e);
        exit;
    }
```