# Creating single insert query for 3 tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, table-relationships

I have three tables in a MySQL database, the tables are labeled address, employee, and login_info. address and employee have a one to one identifying relationship with a foreign key with login_info table. I would like to write a single sql query that would populate all three tables at the same and use the PK from the login_info table as the foreign key in both the employee and address table. How would I go about doing this, below are the column descriptions for the three tables I have. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying it is not possible, and I would have to insert to each table individually?

Comment: yep. not possible. see here for tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization

Answer (score 0):

You can try this structure, mate:

```
START TRANSACTION;
-- INSERT BLOCK FOR login_info
-- GET THE NEEDED KEY FROM login_info LAST INSERT
-- INSERT BLOCK FOR employee
-- INSERT BLOCK FOR address
COMMIT;
```

This is not the single-query answer you are expecting, but this may satisfy your need for your module. Using ***MySQL's TRANSACTION*** makes it either everything is executed or nothing changes. The 'A' in the [ACID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-acid.html) characteristic of MySQL.

Comment: this is the same info provided in a link in the comments

Comment: @pala_ Sort of, mate. I do not even claim this post to be original or 'mine' but this is a guide for the answer to this question.