# How to maintain relationship in datatable having multiple rows?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ado.net

I have a scenario where I have to add rows in two datatables before saving in database , lets say dt1 and dt2. Both datatables have parent child relationship. I know how to maintain relationship between datatables and my solutions works fine for single row in both table. Now if I add multiple rows in dt1 and same number of nows in dt2. How relationsihp will be maintained ? As each row in dt1 does have any id yet to maintain relationship with dt2

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization

Comment: I am talking about ado.net datatables not database talales