# Using JOIN to INSERT INTO second Table with an Identical Id column as the first Table

Tags: mysql

I have a Database (MySQL) that contains two tables with identical primary keys, I have already inserted data into the first table but I want to insert data into the second table at a later time.

The logic I've got is:

```
[INSERT into Table2 (col1, col2, col3) Values (X1,X2,X3)  WHERE Table1.id equals Table2.id]
```

I can't seem to find anything that works like this for an Insert Statement in use with PHP.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization

Comment: Your question says *"I want to **insert** data ... at a later time"* but your logic expressed as (invalid) SQL query suggests you want to **update** an existing row (at a later time). Which one is the correct logic you want to implement?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you really want to update the second table, not insert into it. `INSERT` is for creating **new** rows, `UPDATE` is for modifying **existing** rows.

You do this by using a `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE Table2 AS t2
JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t2.col1 = t1.x1, t2.col2 = t1.x2, t2.col3 = t1.x3
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Solved my problem.

Comment: Mind answering my curiosity: How does someone learn SQL and not learn the difference between INSERT and UPDATE? It seems like it should be one of the first things explained in any tutorial.

Comment: I guess where I needed it for a quick task, I overlooked the simple things of SQL.