# C# inserting the values of checkboxes in mysql without using checklistbox

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using MetroFramework in C# and it has no Checklistbox. Can someone help me on how to insert in mysql the values of checkboxes without using checklistbox?

This is the example of codes I have searched but it is not working.

```
CheckBox[] checkboxes = new CheckBox[] { newRIadhd, newRIallergy, newRIanemia, newRIasthma, newRIautism, newRIdepression, newRIdownSyndrome, newRIdyscalculia, newRIDyslexia, newRIepilepsy, newRIheartFailure, newRIhypertension, newRIintDis, newRImigraine, newRIspinaBifida};

            List<string> checked = new List<string>();
foreach (Checkbox checkbox in checkboxes) {
  if (checkbox.Checked) {
    checked.Add(checkbox.Text);
  }
}
string checkedText = String.Join(", ", checked);
```

---

This is all the my codes for inserting new data and it is running. But I got stuck at "@morRI" because it has a lot of checkboxes that needs to be saved. And the codes above is just a copy on some website.

```
string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO db_personal(per_image,per_Fname,per_Mname,per_Lname,per_Sname,per_birthDate,per_birthPlace,per_age,per_gender,per_nationality,per_religion,per_ethnicity,per_conNum,per_emailAdd,per_civStatus,per_spouseName,per_spouseOccupation,per_childName,per_childGender,per_childAge,per_city,per_barangay,per_division,per_blockOrStreet,per_houseNumber,per_zipCode) VALUES(@per_image,@per_Fname,@per_Mname,@per_Lname,@per_Sname,@per_birthDate,@per_birthPlace,@per_age,@per_gender,@per_nationality,@per_religion,@per_ethnicity,@per_conNum,@per_emailAdd,@per_civStatus,@per_spouseName,@per_spouseOccupation,@per_childName,@per_childGender,@per_childAge,@per_city,@per_barangay,@per_division,@per_blockOrStreet,@per_houseNumber,@per_zipCode); INSERT INTO db_academic(aca_elementary,aca_elemYearGrad,aca_elemHonor,aca_secondary,aca_secYearGrad,aca_secHonor,aca_seniorHigh,aca_SHyearGrad,aca_SHhonor,aca_ALS,aca_certificateSch,aca_certificateName,aca_tertiary,aca_mermbershipName,aca_membershipPos,aca_probation) VALUES(@aca_elementary,@aca_elemYearGrad,@aca_elemHonor,@aca_secondary,@aca_secYearGrad,@aca_secHonor,@aca_seniorHigh,@aca_SHyearGrad,@aca_SHhonor,@aca_ALS,@aca_certificateSch,@aca_certificateName,@aca_tertiary,@aca_mermbershipName,@aca_membershipPos,@aca_probation); INSERT INTO db_family(fam_parStatus,fam_fatherFN,fam_fatherMN,fam_fatherLN,fam_fatherSN,fam_fatherDec,fam_fatherAdd,fam_fatherEdu,fam_fatherOccu,fam_motherFN,fam_motherMN,fam_motherLN,fam_motherPN,fam_motherDec,fam_motherAdd,fam_motherEdu,fam_motherOccu,fam_guardianName,fam_guardAge,fam_guardOccu,fam_guardAdd,fam_guardRel,fam_guardConNum,fam_siblingName,fam_sibRel,fam_sibAge,fam_sibStat,fam_sibOccu,fam_sibConNum,fam_busKind,fam_busLocation,fam_busIncome) VALUES(@fam_parStatus,@fam_fatherFN,@fam_fatherMN,@fam_fatherLN,@fam_fatherSN,@fam_fatherDec,@fam_fatherAdd,@fam_fatherEdu,@fam_fatherOccu,@fam_motherFN,@fam_motherMN,@fam_motherLN,@fam_motherPN,@fam_motherDec,@fam_motherAdd,@fam_motherEdu,@fam_motherOccu,@fam_guardianName,@fam_guardAge,@fam_guardOccu,@fam_guardAdd,@fam_guardRel,@fam_guardConNum,@fam_siblingName,@fam_sibRel,@fam_sibAge,@fam_sibStat,@fam_sibOccu,@fam_sibConNum,@fam_busKind,@fam_busLocation,@fam_busIncome); INSERT INTO db() VALUES()";

            connection.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_image", newPicture.Image);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_Fname", newFirstName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_Mname", newMiddleName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_Lname", newLastName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_Sname", newSuffixName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_birthDate", newBirthDate.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_birthPlace", newBirthPlace.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_age", (newAge.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_gender", newGender.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_nationality", newNationality.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_religion", newReligion.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_ethnicity", newEthnicity.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_conNum", newContactNumber.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_emailAdd", newEmailAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_civStatus", newCivilStatus.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_spouseName", newSpouseName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_spouseOccupation", newSpouseOccupation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_childName", newChildName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_childGender", newGender.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_childAge", newChildAge.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_city", newCity.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_barangay", newBarangay.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_division", newDivision.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_blockOrStreet", newBlockOrStreet.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_houseNumber", newHouseNumber.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@per_zipCode", newZipCode.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_elementary", newElementary.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_elemYearGrad", newFirstName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_elemHonor", newElemHonor.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_secondary", newSecondary.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_secYearGrad", newSecYearGrad.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_secHonor", newSecHonor.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_seniorHigh", newSeniorHigh.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_SHyearGrad", newSHyearGrad.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_SHhonor", newSHhonor.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_ALS", newALSschool.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_certificateSch", newCertificateSchool.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_certificateName", newCertificateName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_tertiary", newTertiary.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_mermbershipName", newMembershipName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_membershipPos", newMembershipPosition.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aca_probation", newProbationReason.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_parStatus", newParentsStatus.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_fatherFN", newFatherFN.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_fatherMN", newFatherMN.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_fatherLN", newFatherLN.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_fatherSN", newFatherSN.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_fatherDec", newFatherDeceased.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_fatherAdd", newFatherAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_fatherEdu", newFatherEducation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_fatherOccu", newFatherOccupation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_motherFN", newMotherFN.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_motherMN", newMotherMN.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_motherLN", newMotherLN.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_motherPN", newMotherPN.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_motherDec", newMotherDeceased.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_motherAdd", newMotherAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_motherEdu", newMotherEducation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_motherOccu", newMotherOccupation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_guardianName", newGuardianName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_guardAge", newGuardianAge.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_guardOccu", newGuardianOccupation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_guardAdd", newGuardianAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_guardRel", newGuardianRelation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_guardConNum", newGuardianConNum.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_siblingName", newSiblingName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_sibRel", newSiblingRelation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_sibAge", newSiblingAge.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_sibStat", newSiblingStatus.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_sibOccu", newSiblingOccupation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_sibConNum", newSiblingConNum.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_busKind", newBusinessKind.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_busLocation", newBusinessLocation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fam_busIncome", newBusinessIncome.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mor_workPlace", newWorkPlace.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mor_workType", newWorkType.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mor_workIncDate", newWorkIncDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mor_workIncome", newWorkIncome.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mor_RI", );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mor_FTE", );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mor_lifeOccu", );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mor_studyPlace", );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mor_testTaken", );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mor_verbInt", );
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mor_dateVerify", );

            try
            {
                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "New student information has been successfully saved.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Incomplete information. Are you sure you want to save?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            connection.Close();
```

Comment: can i ask what error did you receive?

Comment: I edited my question so you would be able to see all my codes :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some errors inserting the data. See
[MySQL Insert into multiple tables? (Database normalization?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697).

The sample code above assigns a comma-separated string (Text-property) of each checked checkbox in checkboxes to checkedText. If no checkbox is checked, checkedText is an empty string.

To write the string to the database, you have to assign it to the corresponding mysql parameter (@mor_RI) and complete the last insert statement (with parameter assignments).

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mor_RI", checkedText);
```

Comment: But my codes in inserting of data is running. And can you can give an example on how to insert all checked checkboxes in database?

Comment: See the code in my answer above. It is based on your own code to create a string with names of the checked checkboxes.