# Insert from two tables where condition

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have 3 tables

Table 1 EIN  columns :

```
id, name, plate,in_datetime,time,image-name.
```

Table 2 EOUT columns :

```
id, name, plate, out_datetime, time, image-name.
```

Table 3 recon  columns :

```
id, plate,in_datetime,in_entry_id,out_datetime, out_entry_id,Processed, duration.
```

I need to get table 1 and table 2  values into table 3 columns using where condition.
I am using the below query:

```
INSERT INTO recon (id,EIN.plate,EIN.in_datetime, EIN.id,  EOUT.out_datetime, EOUT.id,null, null) 
    SELECT EIN.RegistrationMark,EIN.datetime,EIN.id, EOUT.date,EOUT.id FROM EIN_anpr_vega as EIN, EOUT_anpr_vega as  EOUT
    where EIN.plate = EOUT.plate
    and EIN.in_datetime = EOUT.out_datetime
```

I am getting an error near null, null. below is the error.

```
for the right syntax to use near 'null, null
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Insert into multiple tables? (Database normalization?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization)

Answer (score 1):

In your column names you cant write null

```
INSERT INTO recon (id,EIN.plate,EIN.in_datetime, EIN.id,  EOUT.out_datetime, EOUT.id,null, null)
```

Instead, write the column names and place the nulls in the select. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO recon (id,EIN.plate,EIN.in_datetime, EIN.id,  EOUT.out_datetime, EOUT.id,col1, col2) 
    SELECT EIN.RegistrationMark,EIN.datetime,EIN.id, EOUT.date,EOUT.id, null, null FROM EarlsdonMSIN_anpr_vega as EIN, EarlsdonMSOUT_anpr_vega as  EOUT
    where EIN.plate = EOUT.plate
    and EIN.in_datetime = EOUT.out_datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO recon (id, EIN.plate ...) VALUES ...
```

The things inside the first () are supposed to be *column names* for the table `recon`.  (I'm surprised that it did not show a syntax error with `EIN.plate`.)

Yes, later, `null` will get into trouble *for the same reason* -- it is not a column name.