# Insert data in two relational tables simultaneously SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, first is `accounts` and second is `client`. When client signs up, then I have to insert his email and password into `accounts` table and his other information into `client` table with newly created foreign key of `accounts` table. Why is my this query is not running?

```
INSERT INTO client (account_id, name, horoscope, credit, receive_email) 
VALUES 
    (INSERT INTO accounts(email, password, user_type) 
     OUTPUT inserted.id 
     VALUES ('test@example.com', 12, 0), 
   'name', 'Libra', 0.0, 0);
```

What can I do in this scenario to insert data in two tables with single query?

Comment: Why isn't it running? You tell us: _what error do you get_. Never ask a question without actually explaining what you're seeing

Comment: This link maybe help you: [insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization][1] [1]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization

Answer (score 2):

SQL Query you have written is not correct, you need to split it into two statements like following assuming that **account_id** is an **identity** column.

```
INSERT INTO [accounts] 
            (email, 
             password, 
             user_type) 
VALUES      ( 'test@example.com', 
              12, 
              0 ) 

INSERT INTO client 
            (account_id, 
             NAME, 
             horoscope, 
             credit, 
             receive_email) 
VALUES      ( SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 
              'name', 
              'Libra', 
              0.0, 
              0 )
```

In case **account_Id** is not **Identity** column you can write it as following (Assuming that email id in account table is unique).

```
INSERT INTO [accounts] 
            (email, 
             password, 
             user_type) 
VALUES      ( 'test@example.com', 
              12, 
              0 ) 

    INSERT INTO client 
                (account_id, 
                 NAME, 
                 horoscope, 
                 credit, 
                 receive_email) 
    SELECT TOP 1 account_id, 
                 'name', 
                 'Libra', 
                 0.0, 
                 0 
    FROM   [accounts] 
    WHERE  email = 'test@example.com'
```

**Note:** You also need to take care of transactions as two inserts are involved in this case. If you are not handling this from fronted, you need to take care of this at database level. To know more about transaction in SQL server visit [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql)

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: @marc_s agree with you, i will update the response. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `scope_identity()` to get newly inserted `ID`:

```
DECLARE @ID INT 

INSERT INTO accounts 
( 
            email, 
            password, 
            user_type 
) 

SELECT @ID = scope_identity()

INSERT INTO client 
( 
    account_id, 
    name, 
    horoscope, 
    credit, 
    receive_email 
) 
VALUES 
(
    @ID,  
    'name', 
    'Libra', 
    0.0, 
    ''
);
```