# I need help about normalized table in database

Tags: mysql

[Here is my ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RHzQ.png)I have 3 normalized database tables. Employee, Address and employee_has address. When I will Insert (store) data into those should I write three individual query for three of them?

Comment: It's hard to see why you would need 3 tables - unless employee can have multiple addresses.

Comment: should I reduce tables?

Comment: Yes, and order matters, so, be sure to insert into employee and address first, then get their primary keys to insert into employee_has_address (which you could simplify the name with the conventional employee_address naming convention).

Answer (score 0):

welcome on stackoverflow.

Looks like the answer is yes.

By the way, have a look at selected answer on that post : [MySQL Insert into multiple tables? (Database normalization?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization)

Hope it helps.