# INSERT INTO UPDATE on multiple tables - solution in 2020

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP form, which is read from multiple tables. After editing it (adding new rows or just update) I want to **INSERT INTO ... UPDATE** both of them.

For now I found solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15663312/6142142) based on temporary tables, but is that a good approach and practice in 2020? I want to avoid stored procedures, because it's easier to maintain one application instead of two of them (just php, not php & mysql).

I use **mysqli** in my project and created custom DB class.

My two tables are:

```
table_tasks (`task_id`, `task_name`)
table_tasks_assigned_users (`task_id`, `user_id`)
```

When I add new task the process logic is:

**Step 1.** Insert into update in `table_tasks` and get `task_id`

**Step 2.** Insert into update in `table_tasks_assigned_users` with given `task_id`

Comment: I think the best practice would be  left join

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite get what you want. Do you mean `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`? What is the data you are inserting? What are the keys in that case? How many rows?

Comment: Yes, i mean ´INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE´. First INSERT is to insert task name and then basing on task_id i INSERT assigned users to that task in different table. Row number depends on the form. User can insert only one row or make bulk insert of even 50 rows.

Comment: 50 rows isn't too much for a loop in a single transaction with prepared statements. Insert one task per loop iteration and assign the users using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.