# How to insert into multiple table using JPA @Query only?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA @Query annotation . Want to insert into two table using simple oracle query in JPA.
How can I achieve this .

Don't want to use begin clause . **Want single query to insert into two table.**

Don't want to used one to many or any relationship due to some restriction.

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization

Based on that answer, you cant.

Comment: no it not worked Susan.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding.   I meant that it will (not) work and I provided a stack overflow for why.

For native sql, you need Begin

Comment: You can use a stored procedure for this if you want.

Answer (score 0):

It depends: if you want to have two Entity classes or one mapped from two tables.
In the second case you can do it by `@SecondaryTable` annotation, more about it you can find on [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-mapping-single-entity-to-multiple-tables)

Comment: No paulonio , I want to achieve this using @Query annotation with normal sql due to some restriction in project.

Answer (score 0):

I handle this using join and one to many relationship . Thanks all for your support.