# Chaining multiple queries in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm using postgresql if that matters.

I need to write into 2 different tables when a new user is created and I want to make sure either both queries fail or both of them succeed. If one of them fails, the other should not succeed.

Lets say I've a table named users and another table named houses and whenever a user is created I give them a house.

```
user table:
userid(int,auto generated) , username(text), password(text)


houses table:
userid(int) , houseid(int)
```

when a new user is created, I should call following code:

```
INSERT INTO users (username , password ) VALUES ('a value', 'a value') RETURNING userid;

INSERT INTO houses (userid, houseid ) VALUES ('returned_value' , 'a value');
```

but if first query succeeds and the second one fails for whatever reason, that means this will create a user without home. How can I chain these 2 queries together so either both of them succeeds or both of them fails.

Comment: which dbms do you use?

Comment: You should wrap both insert statements in a single transaction.

Comment: @Christophe as I already stated in the question I'm using postgresql

Comment: @Tim Biegelisen can you give a simple example? that's what I'm confused about , I don't know how to wrap them.

Comment: Sorry I did not notice. I asked as the syntax differ from one to another

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization) refer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction is the way you manage what you want to do here, I mean have one global commit only.
With postgresql, the syntax for managing transactions is the following:

```sql
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO users (username , password ) VALUES ('a value', 'a value') RETURNING userid;
INSERT INTO houses (userid, houseid ) VALUES ('returned_value' , 'a value');
COMMIT;
```