# SQL Server: multiple inserts in a single statement achievable?

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I'm using SQL Server. I have a table `Users` with 2 columns `ID` (string) and `Info` (string), and a table `Positions` with 2 columns `PositionID` (int) and `Description` (string).

I need to insert one record into table `Links` with 2 columns: `UserID` (string) and `PositionID` (int), for each record in table `Positions`.

Thus, given Users.ID = "JOE" and 3 records in `Positions` table with IDs 1 through 3, I need to insert 3 records into `Links`:

```
UserID | PositionID
-------+-----------
JOE    | 1
JOE    | 2
JOE    | 3
```

Is this achievable with a single statement?

Comment: Not with the single insert statement.
But you can create stored procedure and call it - see 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization

Comment: which db system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the result of a select statement. For example:

```
insert into links (user_id, position_id)
select 'JOE', position_id from positions
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @The impaler's solution

```
insert into links (user_id, position_id)
select 'JOE', 1 from positions
union all select 'JOE', 2 from positions
union all select 'JOE', 3 from positions
```

Comment: OP said there are 3 records in positions. This would attempt to insert the 3 desired rows 3 times each.